# pip freeze throws "The directory name is invalid"

Tags: python, pip

Running `pip freeze` in the terminal throws the following error (full traceback):

```
PS C:\Users\lhott> pip freeze
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\freeze.py", line 87, in run
    for line in freeze(
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\freeze.py", line 43, in freeze
    req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist)
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\freeze.py", line 237, in from_dist
    req, comments = _get_editable_info(dist)
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\freeze.py", line 164, in _get_editable_info
    vcs_backend = vcs.get_backend_for_dir(location)
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\vcs\versioncontrol.py", line 238, in get_backend_for_dir
    repo_path = vcs_backend.get_repository_root(location)
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\vcs\git.py", line 501, in get_repository_root
    r = cls.run_command(
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\vcs\versioncontrol.py", line 650, in run_command
    return call_subprocess(
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 141, in call_subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid
```

I have Python 3.10.2. `pip freeze` worked perfectly fine until today and I don't understand why. I have updated it recently but I don't know why that would've caused that. I also can install packages without a problem with `pip install`. Example:
[image]

Solutions tried:

- I have tried restarting my laptop.
- Running the terminal with administrators privileges.

Comment: if you are using a virtual env try activating it first.

Comment: [Here's a great example of why you shouldn't post screenshots of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZfLE.png)

Comment: Are you in the correct dirrectory when doing pip freeze?

Comment: @Harsh I have no idea, since I'm not the one that asked the question :)

Comment: That was certainly not aimed at you. That being said pip should work without a venv activated (should freeze the current global installed packages). Maybe `pip install -U pip`?

Comment: @HarshGupta I'm not using any virtual environment though

Comment: @josh-stackoverflow `pip install -U pip` returns ```Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\lhott\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (22.2.2)```

Comment: And about the correct directory when doing pip freeze question of @HarshGupta, you should be able to run `pip freeze` wherever you are. Which always worked until today.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it's just a screenshot to show `pip install` and `pip uninstall` both work. I can still clearly read the outputs of the terminal.

Comment: Try removing the .git folder, if any?
`rm -r .git`

Is it possible that this directory contains non ascii symbols in the name?

Can you try another shell? command prompt instead of powershell for example?

Is this running on a removable drive? If so then check the connection to it/ reinsert.

Comment: You can also try reinstalling python, but it's likely your hard drive is corrupt.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what git folder you are talking about?

Comment: Does 'pip list --format=freeze' work? Maybe one of your dependency is badly installed. The suggested command might prevent the issue.

Using a virtual environment is probably a better option than using your official python installlation. This way you have more control on the content of your environment and it is easier to manage and keep clean.

Comment: `pip list` and  `pip list --format=freeze` do work. Surprisingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actualy found the answer. @Greg7000 saying `Maybe one of your dependency is badly installed` actually gave me a hint.

I had a dependency installed (package of a friend) that I uninstalled manually by pressing delete on the corresponding folder instead of doing `pip uninstall`.  This is likely to have created the error "directory name is invalid". Using `pip uninstall` even after deleting the corresponding folder manually worked and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually faced a similar issue in the past that I solved by upgrading PIP

```
pip install pip --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is mix of Python 3.8 and 3.11 packages. Query packages with `pip list` and find any odd references. Under "Editable project location" column I found 3.8 package location references.

Uninstall manually odd mix of packages with `pip uninstall <PACKAGE_NAME> -y`.